# Why is the Petersen graph not a perfect graph?

Tags: graph-theory

As I understand, a perfect graph is a graph in which the chromatic number of every induced subgraph equals the size of the largest clique of that subgraph.
Should I show, that chromatic numbers of all Petersen's subgraphs  are not equal to it clique number? Maybe there is an easier and quickly way to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Petersen graph is a [Kneser graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph), precisely $\text{KG}(5,2)$.
 By Lovasz theorem the chromatic number of $\text{KG}(n,k)$ is $n-2k+2$, hence in our case $\chi(G)=3$. On the other hand $5<6$, hence the Petersen graph is triangle-free.

Comment: Is there any theorem, that perfect graph can't be triangle-free?

Comment: Using the Lovasz theorem on Kneser graphs seems like major overkill. The Peterson graph contains an induced pentagon, qed.

Comment: @Nate: I agree with you. I was just in the mood of killing mosquitoes with atomic bombs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link --- it shows the clique number is less than the chromatic number of the entire graph.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PetersenGraph.html

Comment: Thanks, I saw it. But, I didn't clearly understand where the proof, that the clique number is less

Answer (score 0):

The **[Strong Perfect Graph Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_perfect_graph_theorem)** states that a graph G is perfect if and only if neither G or its complement contains an induced odd cycle of length 5 or more. Now find an induced odd cycle of length 5 of the Petersen graph and using the above theorem we observe that the Petersen graph is not perfect